# My php script takes atleast 5 seconds to load

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with my PHP Script. If I run it, It takes atleast 5 seconds to load. This is my code:

```
$informs = " AND `id`!=5198 AND `id`!=14045 AND `id`!=6948 AND `id`!=4414 AND `id`!=4451 AND `id`!=773 AND `id`!=14105 AND `id`!=3191 AND `id`!=14093 
AND `id`!=14397 AND `id`!=13319 AND `id`!=4297";

$displayed = array();

for ($i=0;$i<24;$i++) {

    $whereClause = "";

    //generating additional where clause
    foreach($displayed as $d){
        $whereClause .= " AND `id`!=".$d;

    }

$random = rand(1,100000);

if ($random >= 1 && $random <= 2) {
    //pele
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `players_db` WHERE `revision`=12 AND `id`=4570"; 
}
else if ($random >= 3 && $random <= 6) {
    //revision 12 (no pele)
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `players_db` WHERE `revision`=12 AND `id`!=4570 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"; 
}
else if ($random >= 7 && $random <= 10) {
    //messi, ronaldo
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `players_db` WHERE `id`=186 OR `id`=1574 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"; 
}
else if ($random >= 11 && $random <= 59) {
    //revision TOTW
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `players_db` WHERE `TOTW`=30 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
}
else if ($random >= 60 && $random <= 129) {
    //PA Coin
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET balance = balance + 1 WHERE username = '" . $usernamez . "'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `players_db` WHERE `revision`=98 "; 
} 
else if ($random >= 130 && $random <= 144) {
    //revision 0 and price BETWEEN >250000 AND <650000
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `players_db` WHERE `winterupgrades`!=2 AND `revision`=0 AND `rating`>74 AND `rare`=2 AND `xb_end_range` BETWEEN 250000 AND 650000$informs". $whereClause ." ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
} 
else if ($random >= 145 && $random <= 164) {
    //revision 0 and price >149000 AND <250000
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `players_db` WHERE `winterupgrades`!=2 AND `revision`=0 AND `rating`>74 AND `rare`=2 AND `xb_end_range` BETWEEN 150000 AND 250000$informs". $whereClause ." ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"; 
} 
else if ($random >= 165 && $random <= 189) {
    //revision 0 and price >49000 AND <150000
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `players_db` WHERE `winterupgrades`!=2 AND `revision`=0 AND `rating`>74 AND `rare`=2 AND `xb_end_range` BETWEEN 50000 AND 150000$informs". $whereClause ." ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"; 
} 
else if ($random >= 190 && $random <= 219) {
    //revision 0 and price >24000 AND <50000
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `players_db` WHERE `winterupgrades`!=2 AND `revision`=0 AND `rating`>74 AND `rare`=2 AND `xb_end_range` BETWEEN 25000 AND 50000$informs". $whereClause ." ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"; 
}
else if ($random >= 220 && $random <= 100000) {
    //revision 0 and price < 25000
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `players_db` WHERE `winterupgrades`!=2 AND `revision`=0 AND `rating`>74 AND `rare`=2 AND `xb_end_range` < 25000$informs". $whereClause ." ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
    }

    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    // add displayed data set to array
    $result4 = $conn->query($sql);
    while($row4=mysqli_fetch_array($result4)){
        $displayed[] = $row['id'];
    }
```

What you see is that a random number is generated, after that it looks in which category it falls, then it selects a sql query and adds the chosen 'id' to an array so it can't get selected twice.
I hope someone can help me to improve my script.

Thanks!

Comment: For a start. Cases are faster than multiple ifs. That would help a little bit.

Comment: @Matt, yes, but it is harder to use a switch/case when you are trying to find if a value is within a range. It can still be done using something like `switch(true){ case /*expression here*/: ...}` but that isn't any more clear or faster than the if statements.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn its not really. just imply operators in the case?

Comment: It's not very likely that the `if` statements are causing any delay. `ORDER BY RAND()` and a set of conditions *in a loop* probably will. How many rows are there and have you used `EXPLAIN` to see if at least for the conditions, indices are used?

Comment: You might want to put some logging in to find out where the slowdown is. It doesn't help that it looks like you're iterating through everything 24 times. I've found that `microtime` helps when randomly checking the timing of a script.

Comment: @jeroen yes indices are used, order by rand is needed, otherwise it'll select the same row over and over again. 14K rows in the database

Comment: Can't you select the rows you need at once? The conditions don't seem to make a lot of sense, to me at least.

Comment: Put this at the top of your page  `$startScriptTime=microtime(TRUE);` And then put this code at the bottom of your page 

    `$endScriptTime=microtime(TRUE);
    $totalScriptTime=$endScriptTime-$startScriptTime;
    echo "\n\r".'<!-- Load time: '.number_format($totalScriptTime, 4).' seconds -->';` When you view source of a page you can see the load time in a comment on the last line of your HTML.

Comment: @jeroen conditions actually does make a lot of sense, otherwise I would not used them :P

Comment: order by rand is known to be really slow. You would almost be better to just query all the rows out to an array, shuffle and pull off 24 choices.

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai 4.8718688488007

Comment: Do it and post here the execution time so that we can really know that exactly what's causing it to load in more time or there may be something wrong with your browser that's why it will take time..I have seen problem with Chrome etc other browsers which sometimes takes time in loading URL..! more likely it starts loading long ago and then later after some seconds actually load the URL suddenlty..!

Comment: @JonathanKuhn query all the rows out to an array ?

Comment: @Geertje248 No, `ORDER BY RAND()` only once and limit the number of results to 24. However, that could mess-up your conditions so...

Comment: Take Umair's code from the bottom of the page, and throw it at random spots (before the if, after the last else/if, before/after each query). Speaking of which, why are you running the query twice?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Comment: `ORDER BY RAND()` is undoubtedly your problem. Not only are you telling mysql "chuck all the indexes in the bin" you're also saying "copy this entire table to disk, but in random order, give me the first X entries, and then chuck *that* into the bin as well".

Comment: Exactly do just what @aynber said and post here the time so that we can know exactly what is taking time in your script to load in more time..! so then there you will need to do the changes..!

Comment: What @Sammitch says × 48 in the current code.

Comment: @Sammitch how can I do better?

Comment: [This article](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/) has probably the most complete solution I've ever seen. I've also seen it done by creating a second table containing the shuffled IDs from the first, and then joining on that for "random" sorts. Then you just calculate a random offset for your limit and periodically re-shuffle the table.

Comment: You could also simply do something like `$res = array_slice(array_shuffle(query('SELECT id FROM TABLE')), 0 , 24);` though this is still sub-optimal in the long run. Random ordering in MySQL is a non-trivial problem to solve as pretty much all RDBMSes are predicated on neatly-ordered data.

Answer (score 0):

Is not "the script" what is running slow... take mysql out of the equation and it will run perfectly fine.

```
echo 'Starting at: ' . microtime(true) . '<br>';

$informs = " AND `id`!=5198 AND `id`!=14045 AND `id`!=6948 AND `id`!=4414 AND `id`!=4451 AND `id`!=773 AND `id`!=14105 AND `id`!=3191 AND `id`!=14093 AND `id`!=14397 AND `id`!=13319 AND `id`!=4297";

$displayed = array();
$usernamez = 'Some user';

for ($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++) {

  $whereClause = "";
  foreach ($displayed as $d) {
    $whereClause .= " AND `id`!=" . $d;
  }
  $random = rand(1, 100000);

  if ($random >= 1 && $random <= 2) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `players_db` WHERE `revision`=12 AND `id`=4570";
  } else if ($random >= 3 && $random <= 6) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `players_db` WHERE `revision`=12 AND `id`!=4570 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
  } else if ($random >= 7 && $random <= 10) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `players_db` WHERE `id`=186 OR `id`=1574 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
  } else if ($random >= 11 && $random <= 59) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `players_db` WHERE `TOTW`=30 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
  } else if ($random >= 60 && $random <= 129) {
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET balance = balance + 1 WHERE username = '" . $usernamez . "'";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `players_db` WHERE `revision`=98 ";
  } else if ($random >= 130 && $random <= 144) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `players_db` WHERE `winterupgrades`!=2 AND `revision`=0 AND `rating`>74 AND `rare`=2 AND `xb_end_range` BETWEEN 250000 AND 650000$informs" . $whereClause . " ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
  } else if ($random >= 145 && $random <= 164) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `players_db` WHERE `winterupgrades`!=2 AND `revision`=0 AND `rating`>74 AND `rare`=2 AND `xb_end_range` BETWEEN 150000 AND 250000$informs" . $whereClause . " ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
  } else if ($random >= 165 && $random <= 189) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `players_db` WHERE `winterupgrades`!=2 AND `revision`=0 AND `rating`>74 AND `rare`=2 AND `xb_end_range` BETWEEN 50000 AND 150000$informs" . $whereClause . " ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
  } else if ($random >= 190 && $random <= 219) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `players_db` WHERE `winterupgrades`!=2 AND `revision`=0 AND `rating`>74 AND `rare`=2 AND `xb_end_range` BETWEEN 25000 AND 50000$informs" . $whereClause . " ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
  } else if ($random >= 220 && $random <= 100000) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `players_db` WHERE `winterupgrades`!=2 AND `revision`=0 AND `rating`>74 AND `rare`=2 AND `xb_end_range` < 25000$informs" . $whereClause . " ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
  }

//echo 'Run # : ' . $i . var_export($sql, true) . '<br>';
}

echo 'Finishing at : ' . microtime(true).'<br>';
```

Results are:

```
 Starting at: 1461782077.4058
 Finishing at : 1461782077.4058
```

Use `microtime()` to meassure your queries individually to identify exactly which one is slowing you down and THEN we can start from there.